# Angular 2 Ожидание ответа от сервера

Tags: javascript, angular2

При загрузке приложения происходит проверка куков пользователя, если в них есть токен, делаем запрос и проверяем живой ли этот токен. Если живой то все нормально мы разрешаем идти дальше, а если нет, то отправляем на страницу авторизации.
Суть вопроса такова, как заставить приложение ждать ответа от сервера, а только потом выполняться дальше?

```js
//

import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CookieService } from 'ngx-cookie';
import { Core } from './shared/core';
import { HttpService } from './service/http.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`,
  providers: [HttpService],
})

export class AppComponent implements OnInit{
  
  constructor(private router: Router, private _cookieService: CookieService, private httpService: HttpService) {
  }
  
  ngOnInit(){
    alert("Отправили запрос");
    if (this._cookieService.get('token')) {
      this.httpService
        .chekToken(this._cookieService.get('token')).then(data => {
        if(data['status']== 1){
          Core.id = data['user_id'];
          Core.token = data['token'];
          alert("Получили ответ");
        } else {
          this.router.navigate(['/auth']);
        }
      });
    }else {
      this.router.navigate(['/auth']);
    }
  }

}
```

Собственно сервис

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Http} from '@angular/http';
import {Response, Headers, URLSearchParams} from '@angular/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';

@Injectable()
export class HttpService{

  constructor(private http: Http){ }


  postAuth(email:string, password:string){
    var params = new URLSearchParams();
    params.set('email', email);
    params.set('password', password);

    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; application/json;charset=utf-8; charset=UTF-8' });

    return this.http.post('https://url/', params, { headers: headers })
      .map((resp:Response)=>resp.json())
      .catch((error:any) =>{return Observable.throw(error);});
  }
  chekToken(token:string){
    var params = new URLSearchParams();
    params.set('token',token)
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; application/json;charset=utf-8; charset=UTF-8' });

    return this.http.post('https://url/', params, { headers: headers })
      .map((resp:Response)=>resp.json()).toPromise();
  }
}
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как вернуть значение из события или из функции обратного вызова?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/554290/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0)